# Determine the resulting angle of a reflected sprite (diagonal mirror)

Tags: math, reflection, formula, trigonometry, symmetry

I am trying to achieve a simple reflected sprite effect. Imagine a diagonal line which goes from one corner of the screen to the other. Then, a sprite (or image) is rotated by a particular amount and placed at some location on one side of the diagonal. What would be the mathematical formula to programmatically rotate another instance of the sprite (or image) that will be placed on the reflected side of the screen?  It's easy for me to figure out if the reflection is vertical or horizontal (a simple flip of the image) and I can figure out where to place the resulting sprite, but it seems like a whole different level of complexity trying to determine the resultant sprite's angle.

Any suggestions or programming formulas? I generally stink at trigonometry and can't find any leads.  Again, the angle of the line of reflection is known (or can be found) as can the angle of the original sprite. I just want to determine how the reflected sprite will be rotated when displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly, then it should be as simple as making sure that the reflected sprite's angle (with respect to the diagonal line) is the same as the original sprite's angle (again w.r.t. the diagonal line) but negative.

Showing this in an image (with the original sprite on the bottom left and the reflection on the top right):

[image: Reflecting about an angle]

So if you look at the angles θ<sub>I1</sub> and θ<sub>R1</sub>, you can see that:
θ<sub>I1</sub> is the angle between the original image and the diagonal line
θ<sub>R1</sub> is the angle between the reflected image and the diagonal line

These angles are equal and opposite, i.e. 55° and −55°.

---

That might not be quite enough for you to work out the rotations needed in the general case though, so I'll go into a bit more detail. Basically, like I said before, the angle between the reflected sprite and the line needs to be equal and opposite to the angle between the original sprite and the line. This is the same as making sure the difference in angle between each sprite and the line, with respect to a common reference direction, is equal and opposite.

Looking again at the image, assume that the common reference direction is to the right. It doesn't matter if you make this something else, as long as you're consistent. Also assume that the green arrows, on each sprite, would point parallel to the reference direction when the sprite has a rotation of 0°.

So with that in mind you can see that the angle of the line θ<sub>L</sub> is 35° (with positive rotation being clockwise).

You can also see that the rotation of the original sprite θ<sub>I2</sub> is 45°.

So the angle between the original sprite and the line is θ<sub>I2</sub> − θ<sub>L</sub>, which equals 10°.

Once again, the angle between each sprite and the line needs to be equal and opposite. That is:

θ<sub>I2</sub> − θ<sub>L</sub> = −1 * (θ<sub>R2</sub> − θ<sub>L</sub>)

To find the rotation needed for the reflected sprite, just rearrange that equation to this:

θ<sub>R2</sub> = 2θ<sub>L</sub> − θ<sub>I2</sub>

Putting in the values for θ<sub>L</sub> and θ<sub>I2</sub> gives:

θ<sub>R2</sub> = 2*35° − 45° = 25°

---

So in this example the rotation of the reflected sprite θ<sub>R2</sub> is calculated to be 25°, which you can see is correct from the image. If you want to double check though, notice that the difference in angle between the reflected sprite and the line (θ<sub>R2</sub> − θ<sub>L</sub>) is −10°, which is equal and opposite to θ<sub>I2</sub> − θ<sub>L</sub>. Just remember to flip the reflected sprite before you apply this rotation (assuming the green arrow is the axis you flip it around).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed response! I am still trying to comprehend some aspects but feel I am getting there. However, it seems I'm having trouble visualizing the result or math if the original object is rotated around its center counterclockwise or > 180. For instance, assume there's a triangle in your example pointed to the left by default. It is then rotated -90 degrees so it points upward - such as http://i.imgur.com/qUEVSrM.png.  If I take 2θL - θI2 = (35 * 2) - (-90) = 160? Or (35 * 2) - 270 = -200? Shouldn't it somehow come out to 180' in this case? Sorry if this sounds dumb.

Comment: I think that case works out ok. I think the problem is that you may be working with a square window, but my example is for the general case of a rectangle window, so for what you're describing the diagonal line would have a 45° angle and not 35°.  
If you have the diagonal line as 45°, then you get 2θL - θI2 = (45 * 2) - (-90) = 180. (Or equivalently (45 * 2) - 270 = -180).  
Reply back if it still isn't working out for you though, I hope I haven't but I might have made a mistake somewhere.